# My LAN worlds never work. Any suggestions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried everything, the port and IP address way, and the main multiplayer way, but my LAN games won't work. Please help me.

Comment: According to comments on that post it was a duplicate too @TimmyJim

Answer (score 1):

On windows : Disable Firewall on public and local (home and work ) and it should work fine. I suggest adding more detail to your questions in future.

The path to turn off firewall is :
Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Customize Settings

(for Windows)